# hostapd client cannot ping the host but the host can

Tags: wifi, embedded, hostapd

I have an embedded system running Linux and I configured it to create an access point using hostapd and udhcpd. I can connect to the access point and receive an IP with a client device. However, I cannot ping the host from my client. The strange thing is that if I start pinging form the host to the client, then the client instantaneously manages to ping the host.
This is my configuration:
Script to create the AP:

```
#!/bin/bash

iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan1 type __ap
ifconfig wlan1 192.168.3.1 up
hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf -B
udhcpd /etc/udhcpd.conf
```

hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=0
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=3
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0

ssid=softAP
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=12345678
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

udhcpd.conf:

```
start 192.168.3.10
end   192.168.3.100

interface   wlan1
```

output of `route -n`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan1
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is the client only connected to this wireless network, or is it connected elsewhere? To be sure, what's the routing table of the client? Is it running Linux kernel >= 3.6 or something else, including an other OS?

Comment: Can you give `ip addr show` or ìfconfig` of the client, please